# ERROR ITMS-90190: "Invalid Info.plist Key. The key 'UIUserInterfaceStyle' in the Payload/brownie.appInfo.plist file is not valid."

Tags: ios, ios13, xcode10, xcode11, info.plist

I'm trying to submit IOS application to an apple store for review process at that time I'm getting error like this:

```
ERROR ITMS-90190: "Invalid Info.plist Key. The key 'UIUserInterfaceStyle' in the Payload/brownie.appInfo.plist file is not valid."
```

I have set force lite mode (Opting out of dark mode) by the following code writes in `info.plist`

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string>Light</string>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am getting solution from [forums.developer.apple.com](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/121028)

If you build your app with Xcode 11, the error will not appear. And successfully upload application to the apple store.

Answer (score 1):

All I did was right-click the info.plist file in my project > Open as > Source Code and removed the entry:

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
<string></string>
```

Then I was able to archive and successfully upload my project.